pandoc/Rstudio failing simple Rmarkdown document with "Undefined control sequence"
An RMarkdown file such as this one:
---
title: "Reseña de *Lo sagrado y lo profano* de Mircea Eliade"
output:
  pdf_document: default
abstract: |
  "Lo sagrado y lo profano" es un libro interesante por las claves que aporta a la interpretación de la obra artística con motivo o origen religioso. La visión   del mundo a través de la experiencia humana de lo sagrado permite entender mejor el significado de elementos arquitectónicos, pictóricos y escultóricos desde   el inicil de las civilizaciones
bibliography: biblio.bib
---

Esta manifestación de lo sagrado, sentida individualmente como una experiencia de lo mismo, se denomina *hierofanía*, y Eliade afirma que es lo que le proporciona al mundo su entidad, su ser. La experiencia de lo sagrado, por tanto, le da sentido al mundo. En la descripción de esta experiencia menciona *Das Heilige*, de Rudolf Otto [@otto1926das], y cómo analiza el mismo las diferentes formas que puede adoptar esta experiencia religiosa.

## Bibliografía

With mentioned bibliography
@book{otto1926das,
  title={Das Heilige: Über das Irrationale in der Idee des Göttlichen und sein Verhältnis zum Rationalen},
  author={Otto, Rudolf},
  year={1926},
  publisher={Leopold Klotz Verlag}
}

Fails when trying to generate LaTeX with:
processing file: minimal.Rmd
output file: minimal.knit.md

! Undefined control sequence.
l.56 \NewDocumentCommand
                        \citeproctext{}{} 

Eliminating the citation fixes it; it has no trouble generating HTML, for instance. I upgraded pandoc to the latest version, 3.5. RStudio is the latest version too. I haven't found anything meaningful searching for the error. Any idea?
Update: as advised in the comment, I upgraded TexLive to the latest version. However, same error since pandoc does not seem to be able to find it. I've set the PATH environment variable, as well as the RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX variable. However, this last one seems to be rather for direct use by RSTUDIO.

Is your latex distribution up-to-date?

Is it? pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)

Wow! That's mighty old. No wonders \NewDocumentCommand isn't yet defined. Try to update to texlive 2024. You can get it from https://tug.org/

Where did you set the path variable? Did you try to set in your .Renviron or .Rprofile? And how do you use rmarkdown? From within rstudio or directly from the terminal?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I did, but now Rstudio (and pandoc) are not able to pick it up. I used the system .profile, and also Sys.setenv from the console. I'll try that.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I've set RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX from .Renviron, and it does pick it up. Still no joy. I think the issue is that pandoc needs a different environment variable to look up that.

What do you get if you call which pdflatex from terminal? Does it work if you use rmarkdown from terminal: Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('filename.rmd', , output_options = list(keep_tex = TRUE) , encoding = 'UTF-8');"?

There are two issues here. The first is the OP, an undefined sequence. As indicated this comment, Rstudio (through knitr) generates LaTeX code that uses \NewDocumentCommand, introduced in later versions that the one that was being used. If you can upgrade the system TeXLive, that would take care of this issue.
The second issue, however, is what happens if you can't upgrade the system TexLive, and just download and install to whatever directory is available on the system. A priori, RStudio (and more importantly, pandoc will keep using the system one). This other comment, however, gave the answer: edit .Renviron to show this:
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux/:$PATH
RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX=/usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex

The first will modify the path so that whenever pdflatex is invoked by any other command from within RStudio, it uses the newly installed one. The second would take care of pdflatex invoked directly from within RStudio. This finally solves the problem, and I thank @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  for their help.
